# Haskell data type pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Lets say you have

```
data SS=
SSliteral Value
```

and

```
data Value=
SSint Int
```

Now lets say you have `n` which is of type `SS`.  You want to get the `Int` value of `SS`, how would you go about doing so?

Answer (score 11):

You pattern match on n.

```
getIt :: SS -> Int
getIt (SSliteral (SSint x)) = x
```

I suggest you read [lyah](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 1):

We define with record syntax:

```
data SS = SSliteral {
    ssValue :: Value
    }

data Value = SSint {
    ssInt :: Int
}
```

now we define

```
getIt :: SS -> Int
getIt = ssInt . ssValue
```

And now we are point-free.